# Using ProtectedData.Protect() for files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on some code that ideally can encrypt a file using the Windows DPAPI. This is fine if the file can be read directly into memory, but if it can't I cannot encrypt it. `ProtectedData.Protect` takes 3 arguments - the data as a byte array, optional entropy as a byte array, and a scope.

When I use it as below, it yields 2 different results:

```
var data = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

byte[] encryptedDataA = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

byte[] encryptedDataB = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

Console.WriteLine(encryptedDataA.SequenceEqual(encryptedDataB));

// False!!!!
```

Specifying identical entropy also results in different results. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54711fdf-7ace-408f-a7b5-91b670aac8f3/securitycryptographyprotecteddataprotect-never-returning-same-encrypted-value-net-40?forum=clr) is an MSDN answer corroborating this. However, there is no documentation I can find detailing the header or how to read it.

As there are no overloads taking it as anything but a `byte[]`, I can't find anyway of fixing this to allow for encryption of large files without ugly chunking of the data.

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/dataprotection.cs,53f428ec9af8917c)) for `ProtectedData.Protect`, you will find that at some point it redirects the call to the Crypt32 library: [CryptProtectData function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/dataprotection.cs,53f428ec9af8917c)).

In the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata#remarks) section, you will see:

> The function creates a session key to perform the encryption. The session key is derived again when the data is to be decrypted.

This, to me, it reads like a new key is generated every time the function is called.

So, if you need to get the same value every time, you'd be better off using AES instead.